# How to create a sprite from an image

Tags: python, pygame

I have two files of code, one with the sprite classing and one. with the main background for my (basic) pygame. I am aiming to load in a png image to use in my background.

class `sprite` code:

```py
class GRASS (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def _init_(self):
        super()._init_()

        self.image = pygame.image.load("grass").convert()

        self = self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

main code:

```py
from GRASS import GRASS

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

screen.fill(WHITE)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, SKY_BLUE, [0, 0, 20000, 400],0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [0, 400, 20000, 200],0)
cloud()
grassblock1 = GRASS
grassblock1.x = 10
grassblock1.y = 50
```

I am aiming for it to show up on the screen in the designated space but it doesn't show up at all. I am not sure if all the code I am using is needed either.

Comment: If the image is a png file, then it has to be `.load("grass.png")` rather than `.load("grass")`. Note, the image has to be in the current working directory. If you don't know the working directory, then print it: `import os` `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: this still doesn't work so i don't think that is the problem

Answer (score 1):

First, Rename the grass file to **grass.png**.

Then, add the extension `.png` to the image grass in

```
self.image = pygame.image.load("grass").convert()
```